# What is the difference between K-theory and K-cohomology of a stack with coefficients in Vect

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In B.Toen's thesis, he defines two concepts: K-theory and K-Cohomology with coefficients in Vect.  What is the difference between them?  At best, is there some simple example, like weighted projectve space PP(1,2), in which the difference can be seen directly?

Comment: I have improved some punctuation and capitalization.  If I changed any meanings, I apologize, and please feel free to roll-back the edit.